# Issue with XmlDocument

Tags: vb.net, xmldocument

I've got an intermittent issue with a sub that goes off to read a twitter rss feed.

95% of the time, it behaves fine and without problems. The remaining 5% it gives me a 400 Bad Request error (even though the rss feed on Twitter is just fine, which suggests that the problem is at my end, not Twitter.)

Code:

```
Sub RetrieveStories()
   'Create a new xmldocument and load the xml into it
   Dim rssDoc As New XmlDocument
   rssDoc.Load("http://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline/athersgeo.rss")

   'Select each item and put it into our array
   Dim nodes As XmlNodeList = rssDoc.SelectNodes("rss/channel/item")
   Dim i as integer = 1
   divMRSS.InnerHtml = ""
   Dim TweetText as string
   Dim TweetURL as string
   Dim UNameLen as integer = 15
   For Each node As XmlNode In nodes
      'Using xpath we can acess all the data we need in each node
      TweetURL = node.SelectSingleNode("link").InnerText
      TweetText = Mid(node.SelectSingleNode("title").InnerText,UNameLen)
      TweetText = Linkify(TweetText)
      TweetText = Atify(TweetText)
      TweetText = Hashify(TweetText)
      TweetText = "<a href=""http://twitter.com/athersgeo"" target=""_blank"">@athersgeo</a>: " & TweetText
      divMRSS.InnerHtml += "" & TweetText & "<BR><a href=""" & TweetURL & """ target=""_blank"">"  & RelativeTime(node.SelectSingleNode("pubDate").InnerText) & "</a><BR><HR>"
      i = i + 1

      If i = 5 then
        Exit For
      End if
   Next
End Sub
```

Is there something that I'm not closing/disposing of that's sucking up connections? Or have I just coded something blindingly stupid? (Which wouldn't be the first time!)

Answer (score 1):

400 Bad Request is associated with HTTP. From your code it seems the only HTTP request is to load the xmlDocument `rssDoc.Load("http://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline/athersgeo.rss")`.
But you mention that - **the rss feed on Twitter is just fine** - how could you ensure that?
As suggested in this blog you could use Fiddler to explore your request going out to twitter - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/hakane/archive/2009/06/30/investigating-http-400-bad-request-errors-in-web-access.aspx

Comment: I know the feed is fine because it loads in browser and because it has invariably been working 30 seconds before, with no new data having been added to the feed. This makes me think that the request isn't, in fact, leaving my server so I'm not sure what Fiddler would actually tell me.